# CSS - How to rotate and fullscreen an image?

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, rotation

I'm trying to achieve something that I thought would be easy but as always with HTML/CSS it's not the case ^^

I've a list of images one under the other (they are analytics charts) with a max-width set to 100% to fit the screen size. Everything is good.
When I click on an image I would the image to be "fullscreened" and **rotated by 90 degres** if the screen is in portrait mode (to force the user to switch to landscape mode, ie. rotating the device). The image should take all space available and should be centered (horizontally and vertically). Aspect ratio should be keep.

I've succeed in rotating the image but it expand on top of the screen so I have to translate it to the bottom by approximately 30%... But it's not accurate...
To decide if the image should be rotate or not I've used media-queries with orientation.

```js
function enlarge(element) {
  element.classList.toggle("enlargeImg");
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: powderblue;
}

.image {
  background: grey;
  max-width: 100%;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.enlargeImg {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(35%, 0);
  transition: all 1s ease;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<center>
  Texte avant<br>
  <img class="image" onClick="enlarge(this)" src="https://preview.ibb.co/iNVyTd/Graph_Monthly_Expenses_1270.png" />
  <img class="image" onClick="enlarge(this)" src="https://preview.ibb.co/jj6GEJ/Graph_Yearly_Expenses_1270.png" />
  <br>Texte après
</center>
```

Technologies available : CSS, JQuery

Link to JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/8wLbcrqd/10/

Thanks for your precious help !

Answer (score 0):

Try:
.image {
  background: grey;
  max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
  height: auto;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.enlargeImg {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: all 1s;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;

Comment: The enlarged image has to be rotated by 90 degres. This is the problem I have. 
Thanks for trying to help :)